# Browser window doesn't reload with window.location? Router issue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I am using the [Vue Multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) library in my single file component and doing a GET request to populate the Multiselect element. When the user selects an item from the list, I need to take him to a new page. The event handler in the multiselect will append the `NAS_ID` to the page URL as if he had selected a link in the page.

During my local testing, it worked good. **However, after I deploy the code to a remote server, the page will not redirect the user. I can see in the browser window that the URL will change, but the browser does not reload like it does in my local test. Thus, I have to manually reload the browser myself in order for it to work.**

Anyone know what I can do to fix so it automatically loads the page?

Here's my setup:

> `apiService.getAll()` grabs data like this:

```
    [
  {
    "NAS_ID": 100010,
    "Name": "Aeration Basin",
    "Geometry Extracted": "S"
  },
  {
    "NAS_ID": 100202,
    "Name": "Aerial Farm",
    "Geometry Extracted": "P, S"
  }
]
```

> Component `TopicJump.vue`:

```
<template>
  <multiselect 
    v-model='value' 
    :options='topics' 
    :loading='isLoading' 
    :selectLabel='selectLabel' 
    track-by='NAS_ID' 
    label='Name' 
    placeholder='Select or Search for a Topic' 
    class='multiselect' 
    @select='goToLink'> <--- HERE IS THE SELECT HANDLER
    <template slot='singleLabel' slot-scope='{ option }'>
      <strong>Jumping to {{ option.Name }}</strong>
    </template>
  </multiselect>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
import axios from "axios";
import apiService from "@/apiService.js";

export default {
  name: "TopicJump",
  components: { Multiselect },
  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
      topics: [],
      isLoading: true,
      selectLabel: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getTopics();
  },
  methods: {
    getTopics() {
      apiService
        .getAll()
        .then(response => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.topics = response.data;
        });
    },
    goToLink(option) {
      window.location.href =
        "https://example.com/#/content/" + `${option.NAS_ID}`;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I needed to add a key to the router view component.